# Need help stretching background image vertically

Tags: css

I have a background that looks like this :

[image]

As you can see it is not fully stretched. So I want it to be cover everything.

```
body {
    background-image: url("/site_media/resume/images/bg_main.jpg");
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font: 12px/20px;
    font-family: "lucida Sans Unicode" "Lucida Grande" sans-serif;
}
```

if I do

```
background-size: 100%;
```

i'm getting only dark green color everywhere.

Comment: What browser did you test it on? [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) has good support, but only for IE9+ if you're on IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
background-size: cover;
```

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)

> [...] cover, which specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible *while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area*.

Comment: for some reason it only gives me the GREEN color

Comment: It works now thank you very much! After I read the link, I made my bg_image very small, and now everything is fine! Thank you